# turn off built-in WebDAV in office software

Tags: webdav

I mapped a drive in Windows Explorer through WebDAV protocol, it works well when I upload/download from mapped drive, and also no problem to edit plain text file.
but when I modified the office file (word, excel), it will popup dialog and let me to enter my credential again. I debugged the request by Fiddler, I saw office sent the request by itself, not through WebClient.
so my question is:  does there have a registry key to disable office built-in WebDAV?

######### Office Built-in WebDAV request

```
HEAD http://*.drivehq.com/%E2%80%98IP%C3%A5%C5%93%C2%B0.doc HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: *.drivehq.com
```

thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from prior research (but a few years ago now) is that webdav capabilities are built into both the OS and the applications, and that there is an interaction between them. Ie a mapped webdav drive isnt treated as a normal mapped drive by office. However, if you use a 3rd party drive mapping tool then office will treat it as a normal mapped drive and not apply its own webdav handling.

So i dont believe there is any way to disable office webdav support with windows built in drive mapping.